# How to convert UTF-8 notation to python unicode notation

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding

Using python3.8 I would like to convert unicode notation to python notation:

```
s = 'U+00A0'
result = s.lower() # output  'u+00a0'
```

I want to replace `u+` with `\u`:

```
result = s.lower().replace('u+','\u')
```

But I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

How can I convert the notation `U+00A0` to `\u00a0` ?

**EDIT:**

The reason I wanted to get `\u00a0` is to further use `encode` method to get `b'\xc2\xa0'`.

My question: given a string in the following notation `U+00A0` I would like to convert it to byte code `b'\xc2\xa0'`

Comment: @tdelaney: I want to get the literal string `\u00a0`

Comment: @tdelaney I want to convert the literal `U+00A0` to the literal string `\u00a0`

Comment: @tdelaney: My goal is to convert the string 'U+00A0' to `b'\xc2\xa0'`

Comment: @Mark: Let me update the question to make it  clear. I see that my question is XY problem.

Comment: why not `\xa0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are struggling with the representation of something versus its value...

```
import re
re.sub("u\+([0-9a-f]{4})",lambda m:chr(int(m.group(1),16)),s)
```

but for u+00a0 this becomes \xa0

but same with the literal \u00a0

```
s = "\u00a0"
print(repr(s))
```

once you have the proper value as a unicode string you can then encode it to utf8

```
s = "\xa0"
print(s.encode('utf8'))
# b'\xc2\xa0'
```

so just final answer here

```
import re
s = "u+00a0"
s2 = re.sub("u\+([0-9a-f]{4})",lambda m:chr(int(m.group(1),16)),s)
s_bytes = s2.encode('utf8') # b'\xc2\xa0'
```

Comment: I have updated my question to make it clear.

Comment: @OK-Validation I have updated my answer as well ...

Comment: I don't understand your answer. You're assuming the input to be `\u00a0` which is my question how to get it in the first place.

Comment: the first line of my answer does that ...

Comment: Please add `import re` explicitly so beginners don't get confused

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this:

```py
>>> s = 'U+00A0'
>>> s = s.replace('U+', '\\u').encode().decode('unicode_escape').encode()
>>> s
b'\xc2\xa0'
```

Comment: @OK-Validation Updated

Comment: It works! thanks for the update

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `\` in `replace` with a second `\`:

```
result = s.lower().replace('u+','\\u') 
print(result)
```

will give you `\u00a0`

Comment: No; it returns `\\u00a0` not  `\u00a0`

Comment: not in my terminal....